# Fancybox link in title

Tags: hyperlink, fancybox, anchor, title

I'm trying to make a link inside the `fancybox` single image title. I want it to redirect me to another fancybox window, which is inline.

I have a script that makes the whole single image a link, but this targets my document title instead of the anchor title...
I really hope someone will have a solution or a better idea on how to do it! Thanks!

btw: I have almost never worked indepthly with scripts...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.fancybox").attr('rel', 'gallery').fancybox();

    $("a.fancylink").fancybox({
        'title': this.title,
        'titlePosition': 'over',
        'titleFormat': function() {
            return '<span id="fancybox-title-over" style="background: url();"></span>';
        },
        'onComplete': function() {
            goTo = this.title;
            $("#fancybox-title").css({
                'top':'0',
                'bottom':'0'
            }).bind('click', function() {
                $.fancybox.close();
                return document.location.href=goTo;
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 7):

```
<a class="gallery" href="delete/big.png" title="text about the project :: <a href='http://www.someclient.com'>Launch website</a>"><img src="delete/thumb.png" width="115" height="115" alt="" /></a>

$('a.gallery').fancybox({
'titlePosition' : 'inside'
});
```

Comment: May I ask, where did you get this idea from? Is it in their docs somewhere? I couldn't find it. Thanks!